# Gutenberg setAttributes does not update my edit area

Tags: wordpress, reactjs, wordpress-gutenberg

How can i make my HTML Elements in Gutenberg binded to an Array/Object?

Hi,
i am programming an Gutenberg Block now and just wanted to bind an Object to my Block but it does not update.
Currently i have an list of

's and wanted to be added automatically if i push the "Click me!" Button.

What it does is... If i push on that button, it pushes the new Element into the Array but the

Elements are not added. If i click away (if the block loses focus), the elements are added.

What did i do wrong?

```
edit: props => {
        const { setAttributes, attributes } = props;
        let slides = props.attributes.slides;

        const addSlide = function(event){
            slides.push({ title : 'new' });
            setAttributes({ slides: slides });
        }




        return [
            <InspectorControls key="inspector">
                <PanelBody
                    title={'Slides'}
                    initialOpen={true}
                >

                {slides.map((slide, i) =>
                    <li key={i}>
                    {slide.title}
                    </li>
                )}


                <Button isPrimary onClick={addSlide}>
                    Click me!
                </Button>

                </PanelBody>
            </InspectorControls>,
            <div className={ props.className } key='richtext'>

                {slides.map((slide, i) =>
                    <li key={i}>
                    {slide.title}
                    </li>
                )}

                <Button isPrimary onClick={addSlide}>
                    Click me!
                </Button>

            </div>
        ];
    }
```

I'm expecting the list elements to add dynamically while foxused.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Did you ever resolve it?

Comment: I've had some success in doing this to force an update: setAttributes({ slides: slides, date: new Date });

Answer (score 0):

For anyone wondering, this is a [React quirk](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#do-not-modify-state-directly).

If you just push to an array attribute, you're just mutating a value and not creating a new attribute, so React can't detect that a change has occurred ([Source](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/7238#issuecomment-591582347)).

From the sourced post, replace **array.push** with **array.concat** to create a new value, then setAttribute will trigger a re-render:

```js
// ❌ Won't trigger re-render
an_array.push( an_array[0] );
setAttributes({ slides: an_array});

// ✅ Will trigger re-render
const nextArray = [...slides];
nextArray[targetSlide] = 'lorem ipsum'
setAttributes({ slides: nextArray });
```